# Using the allocator for a structure fields of different types

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

I have a custom allocator which instances share a memory buffer of type `TrivialSpace`:

```
class TrivialSpace
{
public:
    uint8_t * Allocate(std::size_t memory_size)
    {
        ...
        return ptr_to_mem;
    }
...
};

template <class T>
class TrivialAllocator
{
public:

    using value_type = T;

    TrivialAllocator(TrivialSpace & space) : m_space(space)
    {
    }

    template <class Q>
    TrivialAllocator(const TrivialAllocator<Q> & other) : m_space(other.m_space)
    {
    }

    T * allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_space.Allocate(n * sizeof(T)));
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
    }

private:

    TrivialSpace & m_space;

    template <class Q>
    friend class TestAllocator;
};
```

and a structure containing `std::string` and `std::vector`:

```
using String = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, TrivialAllocator<char>>;

template <class T>
using Vector = std::vector<T, TrivialAllocator<T>>;

struct A
{
    String a;
    Vector<int> b;
    Vector<String> c;
};
```

1) what is the right way to create an instance of `A` structure my `TrivialAllocator`?

2) And how to make the code work with both `TrivialAllocator` and `std::allocator`? When the field types are defined as above or as follows (depending on some `#ifdef` probably):

```
using String = std::string;

template <class T>
using Vector = std::vector<T>;
```

My idea was to pass the instance of `Allocator` to the structure constructor, but it is not clear what specialization of `Allocator` should I pass - `Allocator<char>`, `Allocator<int>` or something else.

Comment: "the" instance? You've got two allocators there - one which is an `Allocator<char>`, which is used for the `String`s, and an `Allocator<int>`, which is used for the `Vector`s.

Comment: @MarshallClow oh yes, correct... I'll clarity the question.

Comment: @MarshallClow updated the question, the correct question is how to write a universal code that works both with `std::allocator` and my `TrivialAllocator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would specifically take 3 allocators (for example, if you used a polymorphic allocator, you might want a specific one for each object).

You could also have an overloaded constructor that takes one allocator and constructs the other three from it (Only if each allocator is rebound from the other 2, which in this case or with a polymorphic allocator they are)

```cpp
    A(Allocator<char> a_alloc, Allocator<int> b_alloc, Allocator<String> c_alloc) : a(a_alloc), b(b_alloc), c(c_alloc) {}

    template<class Alloc,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<char>, Allocator<char>> &&
        // Next 2 maybe redundant based on what you are doing
        std::is_same_v<std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<int>, Allocator<int>> &&
        std::is_same_v<std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<String>, Allocator<String>>,
    int> = 0>
    A(Alloc alloc) : A(Allocator<char>(alloc), Allocator<int>(alloc), Allocator<String>(alloc)) {}
```

Or you could pass the issue to the constructor of the class and move from a string and two vectors (Or leave it as an aggregate and initialize with allocators where the type is used)

Comment: but finally, what should I pass to the constructor?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Highly dependant on what your doing. In your case you probably want to have the same `TrivialSpace` for all 3 of your allocating things, so just the 1 allocator (a `Allocator<void>{some_trivial_space}` is the usual convention)

Comment: I did not know about `Allocator<void>` :)

Comment: `Allocator<void>` is the answer!